# Error with <string>.append() in ton-solidity: Different number of components on the left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (0)

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, everscale

My code for concatenating 2 strings is pretty simple:

```
string baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
string url = baseUrl.append(url_secret);
```

But I have got an error:

```
Error: Different number of components on the left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (0).
   --> test.sol:156:9:
    |
156 |         string url = baseUrl.append(url_secret);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It's recommended to use `string(abi.encodePacked(a, b))` to concatenate two strings for efficient gas cost.

Comment: Error: Unsupported function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.append()` function modifies the existing string, so nothing is returned.

So you can just call

```
string baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
baseUrl.append(url_secret);
```

and then `baseUrl` will be modified. If you want to set a new variable `url` with the new value, you can do

```
string url = baseUrl;
```